# Proving adjoint of exponential is exponential of adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

My background is the Spectral Theorem and its corollaries.
Let $A$ a $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries that satisfies $A^* = -A$.
Define $B = e^A$. Show $B^* = e^{-A}$
Since $A$ is normal there exist $U$ unitary such that
$$A = U^*DU$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Then, using $f(x) = e^x$ we have
$$B = f(A) = U^*f(D)U$$
Now, I sense I should be able to prove the result from there, but I am stuck. Any hint would be appreciated. I can't see how $f(A)^* = f(A^*)$

Comment: Maybe make an argument like $B = e^A = \sum_{k \geq 0}A^k/k!$ implies that $B^* = (\sum_{k\geq 0}A^k/k!)^* \color{red}{=}\sum_{k\geq 0}(A^k/k!)^* = \sum_{k\geq 0}(A^*)^k/k! = \sum_{k\geq 0}(-A)^k/k! = e^{-A}$? Only the equality in red seems sketchy to me, but it might be able to be justified.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that those $k$ values be complex numbers? The adjoint operation would change, right?

Comment: The $k$'s there are summation indices, so $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  The (potential) issue is that while it's true that $\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n A_k\right)^* = \sum_{k = 1}^n A_k^*$ for any finite sum, properties of finite sums don't automatically extend to infinite sums, and can often fail.  For this reason, I'm unsure if the colored equality is justified.

Comment: ohhh right. I don't know why I was thinking on coefficients for the $A^k$. I am going to use your approach, thanks.

Comment: @Mark Hmmm I see. Even if the problem is specified for a $n \times n$ matrix? (I just edited that in the question, my fault)

Comment: @Mark, the equality in the red is the easily established property that the adjoint of a sum is the sum of the adjoints.

Comment: @J.Ogden Yes, I'm just unsure if that property extends to infinite sums.  I'd assume it does, but don't definitively know either way.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it, you have 
$$B = U^* e^D U$$ so 
$$B^* = (U^* e^D U)^*= U (e^D)^* U^*.$$
Also, $$(e^D)^*= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} D^n \right)^*$$ which is easily seen to be equal to 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (D^*)^n.$$ So 
$$B^*= U e^{(D^*)} U^*= e^{U D^* U^*} = e^{-A}.$$

Comment: You could have just as easily argued directly from the series definition of the matrix exponential without first diagonalizing $A$, however it didn't hurt much.