# Proving $\exp(A^{*}) = \exp(A)^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrix-calculus

I have seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542374/proving-adjoint-of-exponential-is-exponential-of-adjoint) here on math stack discussing the proof that the exponential of the adjoint matrix is the adjoint of the exponential of the original matrix, that is $\exp(A^{*}) = \exp(A)^{*}$. I would like to know if my alternative proof is correct.

My proof goes like this: The operation $T: A \mapsto A^{*}$, which takes whatever matrix and sends it to its adjoint is continuous in operator norm topology. This is true because, since $\|A^{*}\| = \|A\|$,
$$\|A^{*} - B^{*}\| = \|(A-B)^{*}\| = \|A-B\|.$$
Thus, if we define:
$$S_{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}A^{n}$$
we hahve $S_{N} \to \exp(A)$ and:
$$TS_{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}T(A^{n}) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}(A^{*})^{n}.$$
By continuity:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}A^{n} \to \exp(A) \Rightarrow TS_{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}(A^{*})^{n} \to TS_{\infty} = \exp(A)^{*}$$
and the result follows.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: The proof is nearly perfect. You should mention that the series representing $\exp(A)$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore it is convergent.